# Buzzer making weird screeching sound in Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Recently, I've been messing around with Node.js, dash buttons, and Raspberry Pi GPIO. I'm kind of a noob with the whole GPIO scene, so I messed around with it. I have a buzzer connected to a breadboard, and I triggered it using Python, like so:

```
while True:    
    GPIO.output(18, True)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    GPIO.output(18, False)
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

That works pretty well. The buzzer sounds okay. However, my Node.js script makes the buzzer emanate a strange screeching sound. I made it like so:

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
var sleep = require('sleep');
var buzz = new Gpio(18, 'out');
for (var i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
    buzz.writeSync(1);
    sleep.usleep(1);
    buzz.writeSync(0);
    sleep.usleep(1);
};
```

(`i < 800` is just how many times it will buzz to create the buzzer effect)

For some reason, the Node.js script makes a weird screeching sound compared to the uniform, buzzer-like sound that the Python script makes. Thanks so much in advance. Help is appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you change 800 to 80 or 8?  you may have some feedback effect happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node uses an event looping system. When you tell it to sleep, you are actually saying: "Be free! Do what ever else you need to do, and keep checking to see if I have any more work for you to do". Then after your given time, it adds a job to the queue and the raspberry will pick it up and execute it.

The problem with this, is that the pi can't be very precise this way. You free the CPU and can only play the next tick when the CPU comes back to you. This can vary each time and is probably leading to the screetching sound.

I'm going to try a different approach and post back with my findings, but I suspect that holding onto the CPU will yield better results:
- Node has a much more precise timer called `process.hrtime` which will prove useful.
- I will start an infinite loop and use hrtime to control when to tick.
- This could go badly and cause the pi to be unreachable.

I'll let you know. ;)